# Com object creating error

Tags: unmanaged, comobject

Hi I have an error in application i was wondering if any one can help.

COMLib.TestClass object = new COMLib.TestClass();

Inner Exception details
*System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {E2736D7A-049F-45E3-9675-23C2C8D9E310} failed due to the following error: 8007007e.*

I have been looking into reg edit command to confirm the CLSID it is there. Can some one point out what i should be looking into?

I am using vs2010 and the com project is written in vc++, windows 8.1 64 bit. Any information required please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Hi Hans there are few tools in sysinternals which one do I use exactly. Thanks

Comment: Thank you Hans i am getting a different error now. System.BadImageFormatException Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {E2736D7A-049F-45E3-9675-23C2C8D9E310} failed due to the following error: 800700c1. Any idea?

Comment: Cheers Hans I have got it sorted. Thanks for your help.